# Adding Google Analytics tracking scripts to gmail signatures

Tags: google-analytics, gmail

I'm trying to get a simple "Let us know how satisfied you are with this email: ★★★★★".

I am trying to see if I can do this with Gmail, and Google Analytics. It seems though that Gmail doesn't allow this.

My idea was to have perhaps 5 `<img>` tags at the bottom, each one a little ★, with a track value of 1 to 5. They would have a `href` leading to our website with perhaps a "Thank you for your help!" message. In there I would use GA to track the value incoming from the image that was clicked.

Is there a built in way to do this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here may be a solution: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/ut19b36NvKk/wFOfZkWX19EJ

Ones u have the 5 images just set an href to yoursite.com/thanks?start=X and set the X from 1 to 5 depending on the number of star. You can later just add the login on your site to send a GA event with this information if the param is detected (easily done with GTM)